# Pojo Conversion with HibernateMapping & Jaxb

Tags: java, xsd, type-conversion, jaxb, hibernate-mapping

I have two Pojo classes, one for hibernate mapping and one for jaxb.
So I get a `List<CarA>` using `Criteria.list()` and I would like to transform it into a `List<CarB>` in order to send it back to my client as a SOAP message.

Would you have any idea how to do the conversion from `CarA` to `CarB`?

My list contains more than 100 elements and the construction gets expensive very fast.

I wish I didn't have to build a list from A to Z.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use model mapper library : https://www.baeldung.com/java-modelmapper

Example of what you can do:

```
List<Carb> lb = new ArrayList();

for (Cara a : la )
    lb.add(mapper.map(a, Carb.class))
```